# Cannot find symbol class GoogleSignInApi

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I'm trying to setup authentication with Google for Firebase and following this [document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin).

But I'm getting these errors:

```
error: cannot find symbol class GoogleSignInApi
error: cannot find symbol variable RC_SIGN_IN
```

My build.gradle (app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myapp.sc"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

MainActivity.java

```
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private AuthStateListener mAuthListener;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // setup google sign in
    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.clientId)).requestEmail().build();
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this, (OnConnectionFailedListener) this)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso).build();

    if (mAuth.getCurrentUser() == null) {
        signIn(mGoogleApiClient);
    }
}

private void signIn(GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient) {
    Intent signInIntent = new Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
}
```

I've tried cleaning/rebuilding the project and invalidating cache, but it doesn't fix the problem. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Well, `RC_SIGN_IN` is a variable for you to define, I think.

Comment: For example, see the source code. https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/auth/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/auth/GoogleSignInActivity.java#L51

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add this line:

```
Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
```

Instead of this:

```
Intent signInIntent = new Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
```

And Add:

```
private static int RC_SIGN_IN = 100;
```

Also need:

```
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.Auth;
```

Comment: Ah I see where my mistake was. I hate when typos are difficult to find.. Btw, does the value for RC_SIGN_IN matter?

Comment: For your requirement just assign any number to RC_SIGN_IN.

Comment: @yob-v-u `startActivityForResult()` usage is documented [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html). Its second parameter is a key for your handler (documented [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult(int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent))), in order to handle different kind of requests. The signature of `startActivityForResult()` is documented [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent,%20int))